# How do you select a single row by inputting a column name in Python MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I am making a password manager with Python and MySQL. I wanted to be able to enter the name of the service and have it return the password for that service. Here is my code:

```
def returnPW():
    pasret = str(input("PLEASE ENTER THE SERVICE OF THE PASSWORD YOU WANT TO RETURN: "))
    sql2 = "SELECT passwords FROM passwords WHERE service = (%s)"
    c.execute(sql2, (pasret))
    for x in c:
        print(x)
```

It is giving me an error saying that my MySQL syntax is incorrect. What is the correct way of doing this? Thank you!

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: Furthermore the second argument of `execute` must be a tuple. Change it to `c.execute(sql2, (pasret,))`.

Comment: @SvenEberth Thank you for responding! And here is the error message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1"

Comment: @SvenEberth Thank you very much! The extra comma worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
pasret = str(input("PLEASE ENTER THE SERVICE OF THE PASSWORD YOU WANT TO RETURN: "))
cursor.execute('SELECT `passwords` FROM `passwords` WHERE `service` =?',(pasret,))
result=cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
    print(row)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.